# Error in deploying portlet in liferay

Tags: tomcat, deployment, liferay, portlet

i am using liferay 6.2 .

i have problem with deploying portlet
need your help to solve the problem ..
when i start the deployment process following message is wrote out in the console of eclipse :

```
Buildfile: D:\krishtec\training\lr-sdk 6.2\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ce-ga2-20140319114139101\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\temple-portlet\build.xml
deploy:
Copying 2 files to D:\krishtec\training\lr-sdk 6.2\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ce-ga2-20140319114139101\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\temple-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\lib
Copying 5 files to D:\krishtec\training\lr-sdk 6.2\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ce-ga2-20140319114139101\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\temple-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\lib
Loading jar:file:/D:/krishtec/training/lr-tomcat%206.2/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
Loading jar:file:/D:/krishtec/training/lr-tomcat%206.2/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
Deleting: D:\krishtec\training\lr-sdk 6.2\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ce-ga2-20140319114139101\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\dist\temple-portlet-6.2.0.1.war
Building zip: D:\krishtec\training\lr-sdk 6.2\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ce-ga2-20140319114139101\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\dist\temple-portlet-6.2.0.1.war
Copying 1 file to D:\krishtec\training\lr-tomcat 6.2\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\deploy
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 7 seconds
```

i had tried the following things

i shutdown the server
delete work and temp folder
remove portlet from web apps
restart the server

but problem not solved..

Comment: Did you try to copy manually war file?

Comment: The message you see is not a problem. It's what Liferay does upon compiling. We'll need Liferay's or tomcat's log messages, not that of the build process. And a statement what your problem actually is

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is not a problem, but information about plugin succesfully building.

It copies your war to `D:\krishtec\training\lr-tomcat 6.2\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\deploy` folder.

Is that right? So, are you using liferay installation located here?

Then, are you sure you arn't overwriting in a wrong way the following properties:

```
auto.deploy.enabled (it should be true)
auto.deploy.deploy.dir (it should be your folder I aforementioned)
```

Try to check for these properies values, by your Liferay control panel: log as admin, go in control panel, server administration, properties, portal properties.